# Could Yaakov/Esau Berachot crisis be resolved in a peaceful manner?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot

The stories of our forefathers describe a world where conflicts can be generally resolved either by violence, deceit, accident or some heavenly intervention but not through a civilized negotiation and peaceful agreement (probably besides rebuking the shepherds for the wells).

The story of Yitzhok's blessings is not different. I have to tell I didn't see it coming, nothing in the Torah seemingly required that Rivka turns on her husband, Yaakov disobeys and deceits his father etc. I think it would be OK if G-d tells Yitzhak to listen to Rivka just like He told Avraham to listen to Sarah, and they would sit together around the table and split the Blessings in a way that would please everyone.

The bonus part - there would not be any hatred and probably many catastrophes would be spared.

So could that crisis be resolved in a way of דרכי נעם and if not - why?

Comment: Don't have time to write the answer out but you can see it here http://www.yholon.co.il/?p=1367.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Is "שהיו יצחק ורבקה חלוקים בדעותיהם, ומכל מקום לא מצאה רבקה לב להעמיד את צחק על דעתה בדברים נכוחים" an explanation? I don't see how it deals with the problem at all.

Comment: It's amazing how deep, encompassing and edifying questions attract so few participants when hair-splitting, narrow ones seem to attract dozens of comments and answers

Answer (score -1):

No. There was no way to resolve this with דרכי שלום 1. Becuase
1.  Eisav would not have willingly relinquished the brachos
2. Part of one of the nisyonos Ya'akov had to face was to fullfill his tafkid was speciifcally in the emes (or apparent lack of) that takes place in this story (sourced other places as well, but here is one https://www.torahweb.org/torah/2010/parsha/rwil_vayishlach.html)

Comment: Please back your claims up by sources or facts.

Comment: 1.Was  obvious to me from Eisav behaviour A. he argued that yakov stole the bechora after he clearly stole it B. he was a murder and a theif.  2. I gave a source for.